# Custom application fails to start on Rally

Tags: rally

I'm a newbie to Rally SDK and have followed all the instructions in the 2.0p4 SDK "starter kit", but for some reason the example application is not starting inside Rally Custom HTML app.

If you can guide me to how to debug this, I would appreciate it.

Let me know if you need any other information to help you help me ;-)

**-------EDIT**

More information about my debug. i was using Firefox 15.0.1 and i didn't get any script error. when i switched to IE 8 i got a script error with the following details:

"

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 4 Oct 2012 11:44:42 UTC

Message: 'Rally' is undefined
Line: 9
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: https://`<my server URL>`/slm/panel/html.sp?width=1639&panelOid=105518795&cpoid=104144067&projectScopeUp=true&projectScopeDown=false

"

Notice: I've altered the server name for confidentiality

Here is the App source file i was using (a very simple one showing only 1 button):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyCardBoard</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p4/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
           Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

               launch: function() {
                    //Write app code here
                    this.iterationCombobox = this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox'
                });

                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'MyCardBoard'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
             /* Add app styles here */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your app run externally (after running rake debug and opening App-debug.html in your browser)?  After running rake build and pasting the generated App.html into the custom panel do you get any script errors in the console?

Comment: @Kyle: both is not giving any result (simply an empty html page). when i run rake debug, without changing the SDK URL, i get a RallyDev AML login window (which i can't loging) - when i modify the URL to my local Rally server, i get an empty page. Pasting App.html into the custom panel in Rally gives me the same "empty" panel. no script error. btw: i'm using FireFox 15.0.1

Comment: @KyleMorse: Hi Kyle, Kindly review my question again, when moving to IE8, i got a script error saying "Rally" object is not identified. what should i look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root cause found - i was trying to use SDK 2.0p4 while it was not deployed yet. the latest SDK that is really working on my server is 1.32 (which is the latest deployed).